# Why can't I chose my User Defined swatches when recoloring an artwork?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, swatches

I usually select my user-defined swatches when recoloring an artwork in Illustrator (`Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor With Preset`).

My **.ase** files are in the **Illustrator** Application folder, inside `Presets > en_US > Swatches`

Yet I cannot find them in the drop-down menu

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. With Textiles, Skin Tones, and Kids Stuff present, it's clear the .ase files are being seen. I just created a band new .ase file, dropped it into presets/swatches, did *not* relaunch AI, and it shows up in the list.

Comment: Could it be some Adobe CC update confusion?

Comment: @Wolff what do you mean? Different ASE format than the newest update can read?

Comment: No. Sorry, I was unclear. I mean if you have multiple versions of illustrator installed they are in different folders. I've made the mistake with script files for InDesign which I placed in the old folder I had a shortcut to.

Comment: My only other thoughts would be the bleeding-edge version needs a reboot after changing the preset folder (easy to test, just not here), the ase files are bad/corrupt (create a new ase file and try), or it's a possible bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you don't have any swatch files in the specified folder:

'User Defined' points to a specific folder location. On Windows:

\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator  Settings\en_US*\x64\Swatches

Mac:

/Users//Library/Preferences/Adobe Illustrator  Settings/en_US*/Swatches

If this folder is empty, it'll be greyed out.

I dropped my saved Pantone color swatch libraries in there and it suddenly started to work.

Comment: If an .ase file is dropped into the **Presets/Swatches folder**, as conveyed in the question, then it does *not* appear under "User Defined". It will (or should) appear in the list itself, like all the other list items. This is a good guess. However, based upon the question and subsequent comments from 2022, there's some other issue taking place.